# CONNECT BY Function not working with column of DATE datatype?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to build a table of another table by using the connect by prior and connect by root function (ORACLE) so that I have a table that shows all employees and their manager but also the manager of the manager to the ceo (so if the employee has 5 managers above him in the hierarchy, there are 5 rows for this employee). As part of a larger cte, it works fine. Now however, I want to include a date column from the base table.

The base table kinda looks like this:

| employeeID | employeeName | managerID | managerName | dateColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Miller | 45454 | Hawkins | 21/02/2021 |

Now I am creating a new table out of this base table:

```
SELECT distinct employeeID, employeeName, managerName, CONNECT_BY_ROOT managerID as managerID
FROM basetable
CONNECT BY PRIOR employeeID = managerID
```

Now this works perfectly fine and I get the results I expected (load is < 1 second).

HOWEVER, when I include dateColumn (Datatype: DATE) inside the select, It will not stop loading (I waited 40 minutes), why is this the case?

Edit:
As requested by MT(), a few more details:

This is the CTE I am trying to use. Without dateColumn, it is working fine.

```
    insert into targettable(EMP_ID, EMP_FORENAME, EMP_SURNAME, MGR_SURNAME, MGR_ID, date_Column)
with employees as (
select employeeID,
       employeeForename,
       employeeSurname,
       managerName,
       managerID,
       trunc(dateColumn) as dateColumn
from basetable
where employeeSurname is not null
),
hierarchy as (
SELECT distinct employeeID,
       employeeForename,
       employeeSurname,
       managerName,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT managerID as managerID,
       trunc(dateColumn) as dateColumn
FROM employees e1
CONNECT BY PRIOR employeeID = managerID
),
base as (
select distinct e1.employeeID, e1.employeeForename, e1.employeeSurname, e2.employeeForename || ' ' || e2.employeeSurname managerName, e1.managerID, trunc(e1.dateColumn) as dateColumn
from hierarchy e1
left join employees e2 on e1.managerID = e2.employeeID)
select *
from base
where managerID is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason may be that, in Oracle, a `DATE` data type is a binary data-type that consists of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. it **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

When you are **displaying** the results, your client application appears to be defaulting to only display the century through day components and is not displaying the hour through second components; however those components still exist.

Therefore, when you do:

```sql
SELECT distinct
       employeeID,
       employeeName,
       managerName,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT managerID as managerID,
       dateColumn
FROM   basetable
CONNECT BY PRIOR employeeID = managerID
```

You are getting the `DISTINCT` values down to the precision of a second in `dateColumn` but are only displaying the values to the precision of the day. This means that you are likely going to be returning a much larger data-set than you intend and the performance issues are possibly because rather than loading 100 rows for unique employees and days, instead, you are loading 100,000,000 rows for unique employees and seconds and that is going to take much more time.

You can try `TRUNC`ating the date back to midnight:

```sql
SELECT distinct
       employeeID,
       employeeName,
       managerName,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT managerID as managerID,
       TRUNC(dateColumn) AS dateColumn
FROM   basetable
CONNECT BY PRIOR employeeID = managerID
```

Comment: Do you have any other idea? SELECT with TRUNC() does work fine, select distinct however does not stop loading. Also when using your trunc() idea in my CTE, not even excluding distinct seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Jessy Without a [MRE] it is difficult to diagnose the problem. If you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74654092/edit) with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for data that replicates the problem so that we can repeat the issue then we might be able to help but otherwise we're taking guesses in the dark. (And a relatively obvious guess is that the dates were generating many more unique rows than expected and causing the data set to take much longer to load ... after that it's non-obvious guesses and for that we need more to work with).